# How to interpret R stl() output

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I want to have a logical interpretation of the results of my stl analysis.

```
 summary(BR.stl)

    Call:
    stl(x = ts, s.window = "per")

     Time.series components:
        seasonal              trend            remainder        
     Min.   :-2.9127520   Min.   : 2.87902   Min.   :-32.97469  
     1st Qu.:-1.7160211   1st Qu.:10.31844   1st Qu.: -2.80863  
     Median : 0.0410429   Median :13.86636   Median : -1.08351  
     Mean   :-0.0257600   Mean   :15.90906   Mean   : -0.05876  
     3rd Qu.: 1.0959295   3rd Qu.:18.57809   3rd Qu.:  2.05679  
     Max.   : 2.1946197   Max.   :59.88744   Max.   : 18.82706  
     IQR:
     STL.seasonal STL.trend STL.remainder data 
     2.812        8.260     4.865         9.875
     %  28.5         83.6      49.3         100.0
     Weights: all == 1

     Other components: List of 5
     $ win  : Named num [1:3] 1821 19 13
         $ deg  : Named int [1:3] 0 1 1
     $ jump : Named num [1:3] 183 2 2
         $ inner: int 2
     $ outer: int 0
```

What is the correct interpretation of the percentages of variation. They add to >100%, does this mean they can only have a relative interpretation similar to the bars on an stlplot?

My perfect result would be to have a proportion of variation for each component of stl.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21081654/429846 Please don't do that; flag your original question for migration by a moderator to this site.

Comment: I got told to redirect it here? I have deleted the original post

Comment: No, you were told this question would be better here not on [so]. It would have been better if they had told you *not* to crosspost as a moderator on one site can migrate a question and any answers/comments to the more appropriate [se] site. You can even ask for this yerself, and flag your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `stats:::summary.stl()` function which includes the following lines:

```
iqr <- apply(cbind(STL = object$time.series, data = object$time.series %*% 
        rep(1, 3)), 2L, IQR)
    print(rbind(format(iqr, digits = max(2L, digits - 3L)), 
        `   %` = format(round(100 * iqr/iqr["data"], 1))), quote = FALSE)
```

So the percentages are the ratios of the IQR of each component to the IQR of the data. So they are somewhat similar to the bars on an STL plot but based on IQRs rather than ranges.